# Char, unsigned char and signed char as char&

Tags: c++, types, casting

Can someone explain, why I can't pass `unsigned char a = 'g'` and `signed char b = 'g'` 
to the `void f(char&){}`, but I can pass `char c = 'g'` to it?
As I understood after thirty minutes of googling it can be caused by type cast(not sure).
But what the problem to cast from `signed char` to `char` if they have the same range of values(of course if problem in type cast).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They're different types.**

It doesn't matter that they have the same numerical range.

You can't bind a reference to `OneThing`, to a `SomeOtherThing`.

This is the very purpose of a type system: to make *constraints* in your program so that you don't make mistakes.

Options:

1. **`void f(const char&)`**

   References to `const` are special. When you pass a `signed char` here, it is automatically *converted* to a temporary `char`. Temporaries can bind to `const` references. However, what would be the purpose of this if you can't change the original value? Might as well just pass by value.
2. **`void f(char)`**

   This is pass by value. Now anything that can implicit convert to `char` (such as `signed char`) will be accepted, though the original value will no longer be "connected" within `f`. Also you will need to be careful yourself that the numerical range *does* match: if passing an `unsigned char` that may not be the case.
3. **Type punning**

   Your calling scope can do `f(reinterpret_cast<char&>(mySignedChar))` and it'll work, because there are special rules for aliasing/punning `char`s in this way. However, this is a hack, and (contrary to popular belief) is *not* legal for most other types.
4. **Make your types consistent**

   This is what the language wants you to do. Why do you have a function taking `char`, but a function passing `signed char`? Why do your types not match? If this is beyond your control (e.g. different idioms from different third-party libraries) then you can play around with type-punning if *really* necessary, though this should be a final resort.

Answer (score 2):

> why I can't pass unsigned char a = 'g' and signed char b = 'g'
>   to the void f(char&){}

Because `unsigned char`, `signed char` and `char` are distinct types. And because a reference cannot be bound to an object of wrong type. Not even to a signed or unsigned variant of integer type with same width (character types are integer types). This restriction is an aspect of strong typing in the language, and it prevents programmers from making mistakes by passing objects of wrong type by mistake.

Unsigned / signed variants can however be implicitly converted to one another. But the result of the conversion is an rvalue, and a non-const lvalue reference cannot be bound to rvalues. A const lvalue reference can be bound to an rvalue. In such case the lifetime of the temporary result of the conversion is extended to match the lifetime of the reference.

> signed char to char if they have the same range of values

`signed char` and `char` do not necessarily have same range of values on all systems. Unlike other integer types where `int` is the same type as `signed int`, `char` is a distinct from both `signed char` and `unsigned char` and may be either signed or unsigned depending on system.

> but I can pass char c = 'g' to it?

This is because reference to type `T` can be bound to an object of type `T`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no casting to lvalue reference. Which is what you try.

There is however casting to const lvalue reference, so if you try to call:

```
void f(const char& c) {}
```

with `signed char` and `unsigned char` it should work.